# python: stringarray to formatted string

Tags: python, string, kml

I'm trying to create a text from an array for creating a kml using [this example](http://pythonhosted.org/pykml/examples/kml_reference_examples.html#kml-reference-example-gx-altitudemode), in the following lines:

```
KML.coordinates(
              "146.825,12.233,400 "
              "146.820,12.222,400 "
              "146.812,12.212,400 "
              "146.796,12.209,400 "
              "146.788,12.205,400"
            )
```

I have this coordinates in an array already as strings like this:

```
myCoords[0]: '146.825,12.233,400'
myCoords[1]: '146.820,12.222,400'
...
```

but if I give `myCoords` to `KML.coordinates`, i'll get a blob without new lines and with `[]` enclosing it.

I can use `', '.join(myCoords)` to remove the `[]`, but it still a blob without new lines.  How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `',\n'.join(myCoords)`? The example uses *whitespace* separated strings, not comma-separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example uses *space* separated data; the string literals have newlines between them, but Python joins those together.

In any case, you can use `' '.join(myCoords)` to join your coordinates in the same manner as that example.